# Colorbox not opening to desired width and height on first click

Tags: jquery, parameters, width, colorbox, dimensions

I'm using colorbox with ajax to pull in html files.  When I click the link to load colorbox the first time the width and height of the popup are way to small and won't show the images and divs inside of them.  When I click the same link the second time colorbox opens up to the desired width and height parameters.

In the script i previously had width set to false so it would adjust dynamically to the content.  I began having this problem and I tried changing the width to 940, but still have this problem.

Any ideas what could be causing it?

(The site in question is jcoledesign.com)

Answer (score 3):

See this entry in the FAQ:

ColorBox is sized too small the first time ajax/inline content is opened
http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-img

Comment: Seems to be a bum link now, any update? I'm getting this issue, and I'm struggling to fix it. I've tried passing in dimensions and all sorts. I guess I'll try binding with `.live()`

Answer (score 0):

Give the image tag explicit height and width, i.e.

```
<img src='myimage.jpg' />
```

becomes

```
<img src='myimage.jpg' width=500 height=500 />
```

Comment: In Drupal you can build your own image tag with the Image URL Formatter module, thus adding your image width and height in the tag, which solves the problem - if your using Drupal that is.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution if anyone need for this.

```
        $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#form"},function(){
                $('#cboxContent').css("height","160");
                $('#cboxMiddleLeft').css("height","160");
                $('#cboxMiddleRight').css("height","160");                  
        });
```

You just have to set the with and height as per the content you have.

:)